# ApplicationBar on home screen?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've seen some documentation about making a applicationBar but is there any way of adding a applicationbar in the home screen of the phone?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the users' start screen then, no, that's not possible. You can only add an applicationbar inside your application.

Otherwise, you can refer to the documentation you found to include the application bar in any page from your app. If this is not working, please post your code and we'll try to help you fix it.